# An inequality involving the Dirichlet eta function

Tags: functional-equations, zeta-functions

I would be interested in proving the following inequality involving Dirichlet's eta function $\eta(s)$ at different values which, after some numerical investigations, I am sure is true

$|\chi(1-s)\eta(s+2)-\eta(3-s)|>0$ $\qquad$ $1/2<\Re(s)<1$

Here $\chi(1-s)=\frac{\Gamma(s)}{(2\pi)^s}2\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2} \right)\frac{1-2^s}{1-2^{1-s}}$ is the factor entering in the functional equation of the Dirichlet eta function

$\eta(1-s)=\chi(1-s)\eta(s)$

Do you have any suggestion on how to attack this problem and/or references that could be helpful? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You mean: there are no zeros for $\Re s > 1/2?$

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I mean. I have, however, corrected the question, because the region that I have investigated is $1/2<\Re{s} < 1$.

Comment: Ok, I think I have established the result by using that, letting $s=\sigma +it$, we have $1/7<|\zeta(2+s)/\zeta(3-s)|<7$ and $\chi(1-s)=O(t^{\sigma})$ for sufficiently large $t$. Thanks anyway.